# How to add empty cells in a tabular environment and also itemize one column?

Tags: tables, itemize

[image: i want to have something like this table with empty cells and items in one column]

```
\documentclass{proc}
%\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url, graphicx}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% included packages
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
      \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage{cite}
       \usepackage{textcomp}
       \usepackage{tcolorbox}


       \usepackage{caption}

        \begin{table*}[]
      \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
      \toprule
                  & Optimization methods                      & Ref & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Merits}                                                                                                                  & Demerits                                                                          \\ \midrule
                  &                                           &     &                                                                                                                         &                                                                                   \\
                  & Gravitational Search Algorithm   (GSA)    & 147 & \tabitem Robust against initialization   \tabitem simple and easy to implement \tabitem has ability to explore local solutions         & local search ability is weak                                                      \\
                  &                                           &     &                                                                                                                         &                                                                                   \\
                  & Simulated Annealing (SA)                  & 152 & i) obtains the global optimum in   large-scale problems. Ii) not dependent on the initial solution                      & need more computation time                                                        \\
        Physics-based   algorithm &                                           &     &                                                                                                                         &                                                                                   \\
                  & intelligent Water Drops   algorithm (IWD) & 217 & i) get better solution ii) can   effectively jump out of the local optimal solution iii) approximate optimal   solution & update object is single; high   probability of global search capability           \\
                  &                                           &     &                                                                                                                         &                                                                                   \\
                  & Chaotic Optimization Algorithm   (COA)     & 218 & i) Avoid getting into the local   best and get the global optimum                                                       & aperiodicity and local   instability; blind repeat search within the search space \\
                  &                                           &     &                                                                                                                         &                                                                                   
\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
      \end{table*}

       \end{document}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Also, you should probably strongly reduce your example,  remove irrelevant packages etc.

Comment: i have edited my question to the best I could.. i have added the image of a sample table I want to create. (table with some empty cells and items in one column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be a good starting point for you. My main suggestions are as follows:

- load the `enumitem` package and use its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke itemize-like environment, called `tabitemize` in the code below, which is much more frugal in terms of horizontal and vertical padding than the basic LaTeX `itemize` environment is
- replace the `tabular` environment with a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking in columns 1, 3, and 4

[image]

```
\documentclass{proc}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

%% [I've also streamlined the preamble to the bare essentials]
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

% new:
\usepackage{enumitem} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,
            nosep,left=0pt,
            before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
            after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LlLL @{}}
\toprule
Optimization methods & Ref & Merits & Demerits  \\ 
\midrule
Gravitational Search Algorithm (GSA) 
       & 147 
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item robust against initialization   
           \item simple and easy to implement 
           \item has ability to explore local solutions 
         \end{tabitemize}         
       & local search ability is weak \\
\addlinespace
Simulated Annealing (SA)  
       & 152 
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item obtains the global optimum in large-scale problems. 
           \item not dependent on the initial solution 
         \end{tabitemize}
       & needs more computation time \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\em Physics-based algorithms} \\[0.5ex]
Intelligent Water Drops Algorithm (IWD)  
       & 217 
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item get better solution 
           \item can effectively jump out of the local optimal solution 
           \item approximate optimal solution 
         \end{tabitemize}
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item update object is single
           \item high probability of global search capability 
         \end{tabitemize} \\
\addlinespace
Chaotic Optimization Algorithm (COA)  
       & 218 
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item avoid getting into the local best and get the 
                 global optimum
         \end{tabitemize}
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item aperiodicity and local instability
           \item blind repeat search within the search space 
         \end{tabitemize} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question posted in a comment. In order to switch from the current single page setup for the table in question to a muliple page setup, you need to replace the current `table*`/`tabularx` combination with a single `xltabular` environment. The syntax employed by the `xltabular` machinery is closely related to that of the [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%%%\documentclass{proc}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

%% [I've also streamlined the preamble to the bare essentials]
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular,ragged2e} % load 'xltabular', not 'tabularx'
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

% new:
\usepackage{enumitem} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,
            nosep,left=0pt,
            before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
            after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table*}
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LlLL @{}}
%\toprule
%Optimization methods & Ref & Merits & Demerits  \\
%\midrule

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} LlLL @{}}

%% headers and footers

\toprule
Optimization methods & Ref & Merits & Demerits  \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\small (Continued from preceding page)}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Optimization methods & Ref & Merits & Demerits  \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

Gravitational Search Algorithm (GSA)
       & 147
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item robust against initialization
           \item simple and easy to implement
           \item has ability to explore local solutions
         \end{tabitemize}
       & local search ability is weak \\
\addlinespace
Simulated Annealing (SA)
       & 152
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item obtains the global optimum in large-scale problems.
           \item not dependent on the initial solution
         \end{tabitemize}
       & needs more computation time \\
       
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\em Physics-based algorithms} \\[0.5ex]

Intelligent Water Drops Algorithm (IWD)
       & 217
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item get better solution
           \item can effectively jump out of the local optimal solution
           \item approximate optimal solution
         \end{tabitemize}
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item update object is single
           \item high probability of global search capability
         \end{tabitemize} \\
\addlinespace
Chaotic Optimization Algorithm (COA)
       & 218
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item avoid getting into the local best and get the
                 global optimum
         \end{tabitemize}
       & \begin{tabitemize}
           \item aperiodicity and local instability
           \item blind repeat search within the search space
         \end{tabitemize} \\

%\end{tabularx}
%\end{table*}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the code worked great for me, i understood it well, just small query what does this specification mean "{\textwidth}{@{} LlLL @{}}"

Comment: @PoonamDhaka - The `tabularx` environment takes 2 arguments. The first is the desired overall width (here: `\textwidth`, i.e., the width of the text block). The second is the set of column definitions; `LlLL` means "3 colums are assigned type `L`" (defined in the preamble as a variant of the `X` column type that's provided by the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package), and "1 column (the 2nd from left) is assigned type `l`" ("left"). The `@{}` particles at the beginning and end of the 2nd argument tell LaTeX *not* to insert any whitespace padding at either edge of the table.

Comment: now i want to extend this table, its not coming in one page, could you help to make it in longtable so that it breaks in two tables with .. continued caption?

Comment: @PoonamDhaka - There is a generalization of the `tabularx` environment, called `xltabular`, which allows page breaks. Now, the `xltabular` environment relies internally on the `longtable` machinery, which in turn cannot operate in `\twocolumn` mode. However, the `proc` document class sets `\twocolumn` by default. Unfortunately, it's not at all easy to generalize the setup in my answer to a multipage layout because you're using the `proc` document class. Hence a question to you: How crucial is the two-column layout to you? Please advise.

Comment: Actually now i am using \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}, as i have to submit the manuscript in single column, only i have changed the document class rest of the preamble is same, it would be great if you could help me create the longtable in single column only.

Comment: @PoonamDhaka - Please see the addendum I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: i am getting error: LaTeX Error: Environment xltabular undefined. i have already use the package longtable

Comment: @PoonamDhaka - Sorry for that -- I had failed to fully update the `\usepackage` directive: it's necessary to load the `xltabular` package instead of the `tabularx` package.

Comment: thank you so much, worked great for me @Mico